# Apple TvOS VoiceOver mode focus moves across UI views without user input

Tags: javascript, xcode, react-native, c++17, tvos

I'm doing development for Apple TvOS. There's an issue in VoiceOver mode with focus jumping across UI views without user interaction.

The focus goes across the views on its own quoting text and in xCode you can't capture it with breakpoints. I'm thinking it's an underlying process in the hardware causing the problem.

Also the project uses many C++17 native modules that wrap third-party frameworks and are loaded by the JavaScript VM, some are managing UI views.

Has anyone experienced this focusing behavior?